# How to make command-line abbreviations that only trigger at begining of line

Tags: command-line, abbreviations

I have a custom save function, and bound it to `:w` by using an abbreviation:

```
cabbrev w call SaveBuffer()
```

This works, but I ran into issues when I wanted to reference window local variables because `w:` triggers the abbreviation. How can I get abbreviations to only trigger at the beginning of the command-line?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First and foremost, for most cases like this you'll want to use a `command!` instead of an abbreviation. This allows you to create a custom command-line command that will not mess up other inputs.

However, you can't override default vim commands with `command!`. So an abbreviation is probably acceptable here.

Abbreviations can use the special `<expr>` argument which allows an expression to be used in the right hand side. Using this we can construct an abbreviation that only triggers at the beginning of the line:

```
cnoreabbrev <expr> w (getcmdtype() == ':' && getcmdline() =~ '^w$')? 'call SaveBuffer()' : 'w'
```

- `getcmdtype() == ':'` Ensures that you are in command-line mode and not search mode (or others).
- `getcmdline()` Gets the text that is currently in the command line.
- `=~ '^w$'` A regex that only matches if there is a "w" and nothing else.
- `()? '' : ''` A turnary statement that will use the first `''` if the expression in the parentheses is true, or the second `''` if it is false.

This abbreviation will technically trigger all the time, but in the other cases it simply replaces `w` with `w` so no harm done.

For more info see [`:help E174`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#E174) (for help on how to use `command!`) and [`:help :map-<expr>`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Amap-%3Cexpr%3E).

Comment: This abbreviation would trigger if you searched via `/w` as well. It would be best to also check `getcmdtype() == ':'`. e.g. `cnoreabbrev <expr> w getcmdtype() == ":" && getcmdline() == 'w' ? 'call SaveBuffer()' : 'w'`. There is also [cmdalias.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=746) if you like plugins better.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't run into that one, but that's a good point! Thanks, I'll update.

Comment: @PeterRincker Many thanks for introducing `cmdalias.vim`. Simply put `au VimEnter * Alias w call SaveBuffer()` in `.vimrc` and it works decently.