# Make :f do the same thing as :find in Vim

Tags: vimrc, gvim

I want to make `:f` do the same thing as `:find` so if I type `:f abc.txt`, it should run `:find abc.txt`.

I tried to do something like `cmap f find` but that just make any f into find

Comment: Related posts: [Is there a way to alias `:w'` to `:w`, to avoid creating files named '?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2006/778), [How to make command-line abbreviations that only trigger at begining of line](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/12872/778), and [vim change :x function to delete buffer instead of save & quit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7513380/438329)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this maybe:

```
cabbrev f find
```

Comment: Be careful. Try `/f<cr>`. I would recommend using an expression abbrevation and checking `getcmdtype() == ":"`. See [vim change :x function to delete buffer instead of save & quit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7515418/438329)