# Bind :w to ASCII bell?

Tags: key-bindings, vscode

I'm using the [Visual Studio Code Vim plugin](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim) to write my master's thesis. VS Code has an 'autosave' setting, which I have enabled, which means I don't need to use `:w` to save my files. However, I can't seem to unlearn the muscle memory that intuitively `:w`s every time I make a change to the file. While this isn't a huge problem, I'd rather unlearn this behavior.

One way I thought of unlearning this behavior is to bind `:w` to the system warning sound (`echo "\a"`), but I can't seem to find any way to do so.

Tips on other ways to unlearn the `:w` muscle memory are also welcome.

Comment: Unless the solution could also be applied to standard Vim I believe this would be off topic here. (It may...I don't know yet...just giving you a heads up.)

Comment: Good point. Here is a list of supported features: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/blob/master/ROADMAP.md

Comment: Thanks. Actually, it looks like it uses the Neovim API. It might be fully on-topic for that reason. As long as nothing VS Code specific needs to be done. (...is my thinking. Mods should be able to answer definitively.)

Comment: @BLayer my thinking from a quick glance is that, as long as it can be done at the vim level it’s ok. They can also include a vscode path, if one exists, but admitting the latter without the former would belong elsewhere. OTOH, there’s a bit of chicken-and-egg there. I don’t see anything here that’s too specific to vs code, so I’m not particularly worried

Comment: There is one important question tho: Do you want to disable `:w` completely (i.e. even usages like `:w filename`) or only `:w` but not `:w filename`? In the first case a command line abbreviation like [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/12872) would work, in the second case it's a bit harder because you have to trigger your guard only when you're not going to type something after `:w`.

Answer (score 2):

While I normally advise against remapping `<CR>` I think here that could be a correct solution:

```
cnoremap <expr> <CR> (getcmdtype() == ':' && getcmdline() =~ '^w$')? '<BS>echoerr "Dont use :w"<CR>' : "<CR>"
```

- `cnoremap` greats an mapping only in command mode (i.e. `:`, `/` or `?`) when you type `<CR>`.
- `(getcmdtype() == ':' && getcmdline() =~ '^w$')` checks that we are in the `:` prompt and that the content of the line is only `w` (otherwise you might be typing something like `:w filename`, `:windo`, `:wincmd`, etc...)
- If the line is only `:w` then replace it by an error message, (`echo "\a"` doesn't work on my system but you can replace this command by whatever you prefer)
- Otherwise just use `<CR>` as usual.

Here is this code in action in neovim, it works the same in vim and I suppose it is the same in VScode with the vim plugin:

[image]

Comment: I recently  test drove a Vim plugin in VS Code and I just verified that it's the same one used by OP. Based on that I bet this won't work. It had a lot things missing. It felt more like an emulator (like the one in Intellij) than something built on real (Neo)Vim code.

Comment: I can confirm that this works in vim on my terminal, but it seems that the VS Code plugin, indeed, lacks this feature. Unfortunately, it seems that this is off-topic for this site. Thanks for the help though!